# Checking if a module is already loaded in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

I worked at a company that has a custom JS module bundler. The implementation has a function `requireIfLoaded` that allows you to require a module, but only if it has already been loaded. If the module isn't loaded yet, it throws an error. Using `requireIfLoaded` doesn't bundle the module. This drastically reduced our file size.

Here's an example of how it can be useful:

```
if (page === PROFILE) {
  // ProfileHelper should already be downloaded if we're on the profile page.
  const ProfileHelper = requireIfLoaded('ProfileHelper');
  ProfileHelper.doSomething();
} else if (page === FEED) {
  // FeedHelper should already be downloaded if we're on the feed page.
  const FeedHelper = requireIfLoaded('FeedHelper');
  FeedHelper.doSomething();
}
```

A separate bundle is generated for the profile page and for the feed page. `require('ProfileHelper')` isn't called in the feed page codepaths, so `ProfileHelper` isn't included in the feed bundle. `require('FeedHelper')` isn't called in the profile page codepaths, so `FeedHelper` isn't included in the profile bundle. Does Webpack have something like this?

**Edit for clarification:**

If I required both `ProfileHelper` and `FeedHelper` all the time, then one of the modules will be unused. At most one of them is loaded on any given page. On the profile page, `ProfileHelper` is loaded, but not `FeedHelper`. Vice-versa for the feed page.

Also, I don't want to use `require.ensure` because it's async.

Comment: If you question is: Does webpack de-duplicate required modules? Yes.

Comment: My question is how do I require something only if it's already downloaded.

Comment: Maybe what you really need is code splitting. https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: `require.ensure` always requires the modules, I want to require the file only if it's already downloaded. In addition, `require.ensure` is asynchronous. I want to synchronously check if a given module is required already.

Comment: @LeoJiang, you just only have to call `require.ensure` for a specific module when you actually need the module (async), and change your logic to always work in an async manner.

There is no supported way to check if a module is already loaded. I don't really get your usecase either. If ProfileHelper is not loaded yet but you arrive on the profile page, are you just going to error? Why not just fetch the ProfileHelper async when you arrive on the profile page?

Comment: @Ambroos `ProfileHelper` is expected to always be loaded when you are on the profile page. The error is in case someone screws up. We do this type of "if already downloaded" checking a lot, easily thousands of times in our codebase. If it's all async, it'll get messy and confusing. Synchronous is just much easier to reason about.

Comment: @LeoJiang - in that case, what you want to do is simply not possible with webpack. You can do some of it with externals and script tags, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @LeoJiang so do you have an SPA or are you going to redirect and load different pages?

Answer (score 4):

Webpack will deduplicate all modules required multiple times, and modules that are already loaded will not be initialized again (following the CommonJS spec). So, basically, just require all your dependencies directly and you're set!

More importantly: don't wrap your requires if you use webpack. The static analysis to determine what modules you are actually using will stop working accurately, and webpack will bundle too much.

Comment: Webpack since v2 will also include only those dependecies which are used. So use required as you want in bundling process it will be included only once.

Comment: Just clarifying, this has nothing to do with deduping.

Comment: @MichałIgnaszewski All the dependencies are used, but not all the time. I.e. the entire file is loaded on multiple pages, but the pages don't use all the codepaths. The dependencies are for certain codepaths.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is antithetical to bundling with webpack.

The require statements are the very thing that instruct webpack on what to compile. It won't ever compile your conditional requires because those will be evaluated at runtime (but webpack bundles are pre-compiled) and webpack won't have added any of them into your bundles.

What you are looking for is code-splitting: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/

Tutorials:

- http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-2-code-splitting/
- https://formidable.com/open-source/playbook/docs/frontend/webpack-code-splitting/

Comment: The company I was at generated many different bundles for different pages. Most modules don't have to check which bundle it was required in, they merely have to check which modules were required already. Code splitting increases network requests, what I want doesn't require additional network requests.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your comments it seems that `ProfileHelper` is loaded via a separate `<script>` tag, and is available under the `window` scope for immediate use, with no further asynchronous loading.

Also this helpers do not appear to be managed by `requireIfLoaded`, and if they aren't already loaded it will throw.

So, under these assumptions, the role of `requireIfLoaded` is just to check if the module is available under `window`, and throw an error if it doesn't.

So... why not create your own `requireIfLoaded`?

```js
function requireIfLoaded(file) {
  let m = window[file];
  if(m) {
    return m;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find module '${file}'`)
  }
}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a documentation which explains this. it says 
"Despite the various options for loading JavaScript, there is still no way to download a JavaScript file and set it to execute at an arbitrary time. You can say execute immediately, or you can defer until the DOM document is complete, but you can’t specify any other point in time to execute the code. "

for more information [Seperating javascript download and installation](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2011/02/14/separating-javascript-download-and-execution/)